# Alternative for many templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm developing a c++11 application with gcc 5.4.0 2. In this application I have the following template:

```
template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
class Operator
{
    T3* op1(T1* operand1, T2* operand2);
    T3* op2(T1* operand1, T2* operand2);
    T3* op3(T1* operand1, T2* operand2);
    T3* op4(T1* operand1, T2* operand2);
    //...
   T3* opn(T1* operand1, T2* operand2);
};
```

Within op1, op2, ... opn, I need to do a bunch of stuff with arrays (expected to have hundreds of millions of elements, potentially). Like arithmetic, comparisons, copies, etc. I choose to use templates because I'd like to have constructs like:

```
#pragram omp parallel for
for(int64_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    r[i] = operand1[i] /*operations here*/ operand2[i]
}
```

For performance reasons, makes no sense to check types within the for loop with nested ifs. And since I want to support many types, like (int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, float and double, and possibly unsigned too), my code would be too bloated anyways if for each operation I created a bunch of for loops for each combination of types.

The problems is, if I want to support something around 6 to 10 types, the compiler needs to generate up 10^3 versions of the code. Since it would suffice for all possible combinations of types for T1, T2 and T3.

Generating, and compiling all this is taking a long time. So, I am looking for an alternative that doesn't take this much time to compile and doesn't add too much overhead. I was thinking about using polymorphism, but I don't know how to have a similar result, mainly because of the types overload, I'd need the operators: =, +, -, *, /, >, <, etc, too work somehow with all this types, which I get for "free" with templates.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

EDIT: My application is going to process user's arrays, and it will maintain the user's data as it is (type and layout). These arrays can be of any type. So I might need to add int64_t and doubles or any combination of different types. For flexibility, I have a code path in my application that instantiates all possible 1000 combinations (I did this by using recursive macros). So I am really looking for a way, either to reduce compiling time even for this much templates, or to change it into a polymorphic construct.

EDIT2: After some adjustments (little improvements in my generation macro), I am able to compile with O3 in about 30 min. This is ok for deploying and distribution, but it very bad for development. Thus, I'll set an debug flag and compile with reduced type supporting (only 4 or 6), which will reduce compilation time drastically. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: `T1` is generally the same as `T2`

Comment: Member functions in class templates aren't instantiated if they're unused, if that's what you're asking

Comment: @PasserBy That's interesting, aren't you confusing two things? Member templates and class template are different things. Member template won't be instantiated, but I believe a non-templated member even in a template class will get instantiated with the class.

Comment: I suggest compiling this to a static library and use that in you executable. This way, you only need to compile the operators if there's a now operation / operand combination. And the final exe will only include the combinations that are actually used

Comment: How are you distributing your application? I think you've shot yourself in the foot with "For flexibility, I have a code path in my application that instantiates all possible 1000 combinations". If you just let the compiler instantiate the operations you use it will be much faster

Comment: If you really want to instantiate those 1000 versions, you might split declarations and definitions and use explicit instantiation. so only one UT would be long to compile, other would call the template function as regular functions...

Comment: @luk32 I meant what [I said](https://godbolt.org/g/bxDBy6)

Comment: I potentially need all combinations of types. What I am doing now is basically a bunch of explicit instantiations. The rest of my application only uses an abstract class and a class builder that builds the templates. So, only one compilation unit is actually slow. But it is VEERY slow. By your answer I figure I can't do much better with templates anyway.

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah, but it doesn't prove much. I got the same result with a non-templated class. The code wasn't emitted for unused member even when I made the object returned (so it doesn't get optimized out). I kind of managed to prove your point with a `static_assert`, but I find weak as well, since it's impossible to make a non-templated counter example: https://godbolt.org/g/cWAwZ7 It's certainly pretty interesting from a formal point of view.

Comment: @luk32 [temp.inst](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.inst#2) *"The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member templates, and friends"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all these functions are going to be instantiated, the only solution to avoid code bloat is, if that is possible, to find a *common type* to perform the operations on the common type and then convert back to the specific type:

```
common_type operator +(common_type,common_type);

template<class T1,class T2,class T3>
inline T1 operator +(T2 a, T3 b){
  return T1{common_type{a}+common_type{b}};
  }
```

Using category theory jargon, you need to find, if it exists, a [morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism) from each of the class you defined (considering they are categories representation) to the `common_type` class. This is not easy task and may be impossible.

Maybe something intermediary could be possible `T1 operator+(common_type,common_type); ...`.

Comment: `T3` is unused. Do you mean from *and* to each of the types?

Comment: @PasserBy, this would be the optimal solution, if it were the case he could even consider using this common type as the internal representation of the others. But there could be different common type to which a subset of the categories he defines (class Operator s) could map to. The only interesting thing here is a relation of many to one.

Comment: Looks like could work with some effort in my code, since I am basically dealing with numerical types. Still need to evaluate the impact on performance due to conversions.